# How to pull changes for multiple projects at once

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, hgeclipse

I'm using [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with the [MercurialEclipse](http://javaforge.com/project/HGE) extension to use the [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) SCM.

I have lots of projects and every morning I want to pull all latest changes before starting to work. With SVN or CVS I could simply select all projects and click Team/Update. But the `Team/Pull` command of MercurialEclipse is disabled when multiple projects are selected.

So currently I have to call `Team/Pull` on each project separately. That's really annoying. How can I pull changes for multiple projects in one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use an external script than trying to do it directly from Eclipse.

See for instance:

- [Mercurial Repository Nightly Pull from a subdirectory on a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317964/mercurial-repository-nightly-pull-from-a-subdirectory-on-a-server) (for the idea)
- [Updated Mercurial Batch Pull/Update Python Script](http://bluebill.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/updated-mercurial-batch-pullupdate-python-script/) (for an actual complete script)

Then a simple refresh in your Eclipse environment would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

You could highlight them all, right click, and choose synchronize.  You could then pull from this view if desired (plus it will show you changes).

Answer (score 0):

One not-quite-what-was-intended solution would be to make each a subrepo of of parent repository.  Something with a `.hgsub` file of:

```
project1 = project1
project2 = project2
...
```

would be enough for 'hg pull' in the top level to do a pull in all of them.

You're probably better off just scripting it though.  I don't know what eclipse offers for scripting but from the unix command line that would be:

```
for therepo in $(find /my/project/root -type -d -name .hg) ; do
  hg --repository ${therepo%.hg} pull
done
```

Comment: Subrepositories wont work since they are pulled in as needed when you do `hg update` in the outer repository, not when you do `hg pull` there. Also, someone would have to do `hg pull` in each subrepo like you suggest and then commit the changed `.hgsubstate` file in the main repo.